# error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1

Tags: windows, rust, x86-64

Проблема возникает при компиляции следующего куска кода на Rust:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let resp = reqwest::blocking::get("https://habr.com/ru/all/")?
        .json::<HashMap<String, String>>()?;
    println!("{:#?}", resp);
    Ok(())
}
```

В файле зависимости следующие конфигурации:

```
[package]
name = "weather"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
```

Код пытаюсь скомпилировать из под Windows 10 так же, запуск кода в wls тоже не помог.
По другим решениям устанавливал библиотеку msys2-x86_64-20220603 думал в ней проблема но нет  это не решило.
Так же проверял пакеты Rust все установлено но код все равно падает с ошибкой.

Развернутый лог:

```
= note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\self-contained\\crt2.o" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustcYB0ZuK\\symbols.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.16q2ytcbljbd9ffw.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.17eih5sefmryda6u.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.18fv2ehntib3xgd0.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.1ao63ladgcbmw54x.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.1b05c8dnon2lr3hi.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.1vhvgbscu36m9kly.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.2180riju7tvo8o2k.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.239d11fksh8lwz7b.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.27x0tvmqgw1fab0c.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.2eyx1nso9hfopzyt.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.2iczy8uu6xo1zqco.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.2ns9idm3xwfnuq8s.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.2r1u5wruz5kl9l19.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.2w370v3dvms2hb0s.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.31ez8oarrgp4bi1s.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3e9ky5wxr7s3b6yo.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3ff51h498rdgdxzy.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3gco5rtaoj772pkx.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3jnp16u8tipqie2l.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3nuka819ysikccua.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3te7zb5plhqris87.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3u0ivouf9vyo7z8h.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.3xdis5cddi4ozoxf.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.411uw1i7nypmaah.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.460sw8cah1s1h23j.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4724eepagiox3c85.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4agd0x0t4rjh4pb0.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4cacm0zu00n7937a.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4mdxyxeqav6j7wk9.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4r45jhm54jje5rjf.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4t62hjk31tvsxjnd.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4teaxmyxawy5u1i0.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4v7rwepjhu4wibi2.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4vwfhhovritka3ya.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4wddor1zgqicu01y.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.4zt5kirkf225gzzf.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.50lt915dwptkkfoo.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.52911x1uro1c1pms.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.5388qzieth5ze4wj.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.55rdasj2pf4pp47r.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.oarmqb5mbotg1q3.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.qe2s6zznf1dit36.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.rqnt1u8152s6qz7.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.smvjolszdhfwyru.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.t4p27uhb0mx7c7.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.yd5umzy7yjg428y.rcgu.o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.510kvph8355c9zyo.rcgu.o" "-L" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\windows_x86_64_gnu-0.42.2\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-0.4.0\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\windows_x86_64_gnu-0.48.0\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libreqwest-cc8abd545116580b.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhyper_tls-f639805964d21624.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbase64-623b98010ae9cab9.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinreg-fc64529401deb344.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libipnet-1f6a9a643490f9d1.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtokio_native_tls-4eda9f951239d4bf.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde_urlencoded-2d8e3c51a96f1f04.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmime-3de2992370490d2a.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libencoding_rs-0ece695b9bd3b0fc.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde_json-9f74d96d70e831ba.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libryu-2a90afd50eab66f6.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde-57191f00d96fd6fb.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libnative_tls-8a98dd824a1ad8b8.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libschannel-eddbeb25d6906abc.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwindows_sys-8dad827e265ccaa6.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhyper-08f2a03cbbbaa9d0.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwant-98ab191f5ed99d1b.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtry_lock-023779648e70c837.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhttparse-3606cf3f32220c2d.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libh2-fc2e32e484860ab5.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libindexmap-fb9c172020abd41c.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhashbrown-dbd8eed414242a94.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtokio_util-3760b0bd5ff46387.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_sink-adc4dadd346d8fd2.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtower_service-33adbbdd76c2c2fe.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtracing-6462ed6461a8da39.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtracing_core-a7f9531d134db1c0.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libonce_cell-1169b15c9fd08d3f.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_channel-6aded0581a80b327.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtokio-52b18625fbd19429.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libnum_cpus-26e5a69ae3a2607c.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsocket2-c1e6b9a74a7539a0.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinapi-4a4d64cebc0c9775.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwindows_sys-a64d915e6ddcaa0b.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwindows_targets-71ced2c925789287.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmio-e60de6651f59aee7.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwindows_sys-048418a0f91b4eed.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhttp_body-e4c06eb5f885a576.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblog-a7fcf73ff27643ca.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcfg_if-27b9f6d69f545d5e.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_util-5a20e2624b91db14.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmemchr-26ca9db4e2bdcf17.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_io-f6305e43ec0e14e3.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libslab-bb19be7283dfba9c.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpin_project_lite-7d231cf20c891cc6.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_task-e77a8c4ae7bf4a1c.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpin_utils-12b7b71c0b5156f0.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_core-9499888199340755.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\liburl-082da83c13cbfcfb.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libidna-ebd0d26c89e33712.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_normalization-4badded73fddfc62.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtinyvec-cf883c3794cdc88b.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtinyvec_macros-2ece721ca1946b3a.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_bidi-0d3865457b1cad93.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libform_urlencoded-f5e3131c04c0f513.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpercent_encoding-bae3004373647e2c.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhttp-69eefdd0106acc1c.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libitoa-58cc4af262ef2140.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbytes-82ae20e9049722ef.rlib" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfnv-e7d40075e1d1a412.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-1fe2db36b331a405.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-d5574951733163b1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-58b89c14e9d52af2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-423c086472264e81.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-996081c68a5bd5ed.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-74655fcf56ff56f7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-3900c8efcf588157.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-f10917bde57c3f51.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-462dd362bcb2eb67.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-46cdd015ca663676.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libadler-b6c6976a9174d9e0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-996e77d005eff6e4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-1618bdd73007a12f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-f66f3c16479b453f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-43699abf055ea7d4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-5707fc020ef12752.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-46b625dbb6da6653.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-174883968af2b81f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-0a3eb1cc511d1482.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lwindows" "-lwinapi_advapi32" "-lwinapi_cfgmgr32" "-lwinapi_fwpuclnt" "-lwinapi_kernel32" "-lwinapi_ntdll" "-lwinapi_user32" "-lwinapi_ws2_32" "-lwindows.0.48.0" "-lntdll" "-lwindows" "-lkernel32" "-ladvapi32" "-luserenv" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-lbcrypt" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-nostartfiles" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\self-contained" "-o" "E:\\PET_PROJECTS\\RUST\\weather\\target\\debug\\deps\\weather-15d35222d8c7acc4.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\\Users\\hemen\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: ld: cannot find -lntdll
```

Comment: Вам точно нужен gcc? Под windows было бы проще использовать msvc.